# How to add Interceptor to Volley API request (Android)?

Tags: java, android, api, android-volley

I have too many volley requests I want to add an interceptor to each request to track each request details.

Interceptor used [Chucker Interceptor](https://github.com/jgilfelt/chuck).

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Nowadays there's no reason to use Volley (also advised by Google). Use Retrofit with OkHttp, which allows interceptors with ease

Comment: @Zun it's old big code i don't have time & order to convert it all to retrofit, I'm stuck with it.